# performing git describe in libgit2

Tags: c++, libgit2

I want to work this like "git describe" is working in terminal.

How can I get current tag of my repo? Now my program is printing

09B8A518

Everytime I try that, this number is different so I dont think it is commit ID or so.

When I perform "git describe" in terminal, output is "v0.1.2"

Is there a way to do that?

By the way, how can I convert "git_describe_result *out;" to string?

```
    string path = C://my/local/repo;
    string result;
    git_libgit2_init();

    const char * REPO_PATH = path.c_str();
    git_repository * repo = nullptr;
    git_repository_open(&repo, REPO_PATH);

    git_describe_result *out;
    git_describe_options opts = GIT_DESCRIBE_OPTIONS_INIT;
    opts.version = GIT_DESCRIBE_FORMAT_OPTIONS_VERSION;  // GIT_DESCRIBE_OPTIONS_VERSION;

    git_describe_workdir(&out, repo, &opts);
    cout << out << endl;

    git_describe_result_free(out);
    git_repository_free(repo);
    git_libgit2_shutdown();
```

Comment: You're printing the pointer. The real question here is how to format `git_describe_result` as a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert `git_describe_result` into a string with `git_describe_format`.

Answer (score 1):

Now this works for me

```
            string path = C://my/local/repo;
            string result;
            git_libgit2_init();

            const char * REPO_PATH = path.c_str();
            git_repository * repo = nullptr;
            git_repository_open(&repo, REPO_PATH);
            git_describe_result *out;
            git_describe_options opts = GIT_DESCRIBE_OPTIONS_INIT;
 // ---------------------------------------
            // I added this
            opts.describe_strategy = GIT_DESCRIBE_ALL;
            opts.max_candidates_tags = 0;
            opts.only_follow_first_parent = 1;
 // ---------------------------------------
            git_describe_workdir(&out, repo, &opts);

    // --------------------------------------

    // and also this
                git_buf out1 = { 0 };
                const git_describe_format_options opts1=GIT_DESCRIBE_FORMAT_OPTIONS_INIT;
                git_describe_format(&out1, out, &opts1);
                result = out1.ptr;
                cout << result << endl;

    // ---------------------------------------
            git_describe_result_free(out);
            git_repository_free(repo);
            git_libgit2_shutdown();
```